# Global and Local variable, running into problem with connect()

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, global-variables

I have this code:
mainclass.cpp file:

```
#include "mainclass.h"
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QApplication>

Domino *domino = new Domino();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qDebug()<< __FUNCTION__;
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainClass w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

MainClass::MainClass(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    qDebug()<< __FUNCTION__;
    //Domino *domino = new Domino();
    connect(domino, SIGNAL(OneImageReceivedSignal()), this, SLOT(OneImageReceivedSlot()));
    domino->ReceiveAnImage();
}

void MainClass::OneImageReceivedSlot(){
    qDebug()<< __FUNCTION__;
}
```

domino.cpp file:

```
#include "domino.h"
#include <QtDebug>
Domino::Domino(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    qDebug()<< __FUNCTION__;
    cdl_img_acquisition_= new CDLImageAcquisition();
    connect(cdl_img_acquisition_, SIGNAL(OneImageReceivedSignal()), this, SIGNAL(OneImageReceivedSignal()));
}


void Domino::ReceiveAnImage(){
    qDebug()<<__FUNCTION__;
    cdl_img_acquisition_->ReceiveAnImage();
}


CDLImageAcquisition *Domino::get_cdl_img_acquisition(){
    qDebug()<< __FUNCTION__;
    return this->cdl_img_acquisition_;
}
```

icdlimageacquisition.cpp file:

```
#include "cdlimageacquisition.h"
#include<QtDebug>

CDLImageAcquisition::CDLImageAcquisition(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    qDebug()<< __FUNCTION__;
    icdlcam_=new ICDLCam();
    connect(icdlcam_, SIGNAL(OneImageReceivedSignal()),this, SIGNAL(OneImageReceivedSignal()));
}

void CDLImageAcquisition::ReceiveAnImage(){
    qDebug()<<__FUNCTION__;
    icdlcam_->ReceiveAnImage();
}

ICDLCam *CDLImageAcquisition::get_cdl_cam(){
    qDebug()<< __FUNCTION__;
    return this->icdlcam_;
}
```

icdlcam.cpp file:

```
#include "icdlcam.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <QtDebug>

ICDLCam::ICDLCam(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    qDebug()<< __FUNCTION__;
}


void ICDLCam::ReceiveAnImage(){
    qDebug()<<__FUNCTION__;
    emit OneImageReceivedSignal();
}
```

When I build and run with MSVC 2015, or 2019, the program crashed as below:

```
15:57:25: Starting C:\Users\User\source\DL01-SOFTWARE\build-DOMINO-TEST2-Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug\Lib\debug\Lib.exe ...
Domino::Domino
CDLImageAcquisition::CDLImageAcquisition
ICDLCam::ICDLCam
15:57:27: The program has unexpectedly finished.
15:57:27: The process was ended forcefully.
15:57:27: C:\Users\User\source\DL01-SOFTWARE\build-DOMINO-TEST2-Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug\Lib\debug\Lib.exe crashed.
```

The debugger crashes at `connect(icdlcam_, SIGNAL(OneImageReceivedSignal()),this, SIGNAL(OneImageReceivedSignal()));` of the CDLImageAcquisition constructor.

It shows this message dialog: "Exception triggered: The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception. Stopped in thread 0 by: Exception at 0x7fff9dd8da2a, code:0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags = 0x0 (first chance).

The program does not crash when:

- I declare and initialize `domino` variable inside the local scope of the `MainClass`constructor
- I build and run with the MinGW compiler regardless of the scope of the `domino`variable.

I have to use Pylon API in Windows that does not support MinGW compiler, and I also need the global scope of the `domino` variable later. I also tried putting it as a static member of a class, but the result is the same.

Comment: And you wouldn't want to call [`a.exec()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#exec)? See [tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/tutorial1-01.html). Likely that you are simply exiting too early. Additionally, consider usage of smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr<Domino>`).

Comment: Thanks, I just edited the main() function. It was deleted because I tried to clean the code before posting the question, the bug is the same.

Comment: I tried std::unique_ptr<Domino> domino(new Domino()); then connect(domino.get(), SIGNAL(OneImageReceivedSignal()), this, SLOT(OneImageReceivedSlot())); It gives same error.

Comment: Does it help to make the Domino variable static? `static Domino *domino = new Domino();`.

Comment: @E4z9 As I mentioned in the post, I tried `static` but it turns out to be the same result as the global since I have to initialize it outside of the local scope of the function.

Comment: `static` at namespace scope just specifies that the variable is not visible from other compilation units (i. e. files), nothing more. Sure it won't have any influence on the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an explanation on what *exactly* happens, I can only assume that there is some Qt magic happening here with the Win32 API.

For GUI (non-console) applications, the starting point is not `main`, but `WinMain`, which is why Qt redefines `main` to `qMain` (https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/kernel/qwindowdefs.h?h=5.15#n114) and links to a special qtmain static library (https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/winmain/?h=5.15), the details of which elude me...

Anyhow, a minimal example to reproduce the issue:

main.cpp:

```
#include <QObject>

class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Test() {
        connect(this, &Test::sig, this, &Test::slot);
    }

    void slot() {}
signals:
    void sig();
};

Test *t = new Test;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
//    Test t;
     return 0;
}

#include "main.moc"
```

test.pro

```
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

The above crashes.

If you create the `Test` object in `main` instead of globally, it no longer crashes.

If you build it as a console application, it no longer crashes, i.e. when changing the CONFIG line to `CONFIG += c++11 console`, rerunning qmake & rebuilding.

*Bottom line: You cannot use `connect` before `main`.*

Options that you have, besides not calling `connect` in the constructor of your global object (or not using a global object):

### Allocate the global object in main

```
Test *t = nullptr;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    t = new Test;
    return 0;
}
```

### Use Q_GLOBAL_STATIC

> The object created by Q_GLOBAL_STATIC initializes itself on the first use, which means that it will not increase the application or the library's load time. Additionally, the object is initialized in a thread-safe manner on all platforms.

```
Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(Test, t)
```

somewhere else access the object either by calling methods with `t->someMethod()` or access the pointer with `t()`, e.g. `connect(t(), &Test::sig, .....)`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This solves my problem. In addition to answer why it works with MINGW compiler but not MSVC compiler, I debugged again and noticed that when using global initialization before `main()` (e.g `Test t = new Test`). MSVC starts with dynamic initialization. Therefore, before `main()`, Test object is empty at the moment of `connect()` function is called. The application crashes at this point. MINGW starts with static initialization, there is no problem with `connect()`.

Comment: If you like the answer and think it solves your issue, please consider "accepting" it.